# WordPress - How to reduce the size of wp_old_cache table?

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

The wp_old_cache on my WordPress website is 140MB. The site is not high traffic at all. I have used W3 Cache in the past, but it's disabled. I've cleared the cache with it, I have optimised tables using WordPress Datatbase plugin, I have used the plugin Sweep as well, but the size of that table is just huge. Can anyone help? IS this table content necessary?
There's also another cache table wp_old_lcache of 42mb.
Thanks